# Keyboard shortcut for clearing flag in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How to remove quickly a flag from an email in Outlook ? I first found this solution but too complex : <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Outlook 2016 you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to clear the flag on a message.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted.  This shortcut is working in Outlook 365 too.

Comment: Works in Outlook 2010 also.

Comment: To add to this, `Insert` (without `Alt`) will toggle between flagged and completed.

Answer (score 3):

No shortcut to directly clear a flag in Outlook. You may consider to create a Quick Step and assign a shortcut key to the quick step:

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found an easy solution : add a quick access button calling the built in function 'Clear flag' --> so I can access it with only one shortcut (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> in my case but it depends on the position of your button in the quick access toolbar).

Anyone with a better solution ?